# Create tar in current working directory without the entire parent directory?

Tags: bash, tar

I want to tar a directory (including that directory itself) but I do not want the parent directory and I want to save it in the current working directory.

I am using:

'''cd /home/user/directory'''

'''tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz *'''

but it only saves the files and folders inside of /directory, not /directory itself as the head directory of the tar.

Further, I want the bash script to save the tar file in the current working directory of the user. I'm quite new to bash scripting so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to mention, I thought I was doing the right thing when I used: tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz /home/user/directory before, but then it also saves the /home and /user directories as well, which I don't want

Comment: `cd ..; tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz directory`

Comment: `cd /home/user/ && tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz directory`.

Comment: `cd .... || { echo "Something went wrong!" >&2; exit 1; } ;  ....`  Just in case `cd` failed for one reason or another you will have an error and the rest of the code/command will not be executed...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add prefixes (and manipulate filenames, paths) in tar archives by using `--transform` (from `man tar`):

> --transform=EXPRESSION, --xform=EXPRESSION
>
> use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names

You'd like to add a directory, which can be done with the following `transform` expression:

```
's,^,directory/,'
```

`,` = delimiter, could be basically anything as long as the same characters is used in all places

`s` = search and replace

`^` = beginning of line

`directory/` = text of choice

Basically it says, "replace the beginning of the line with `directory/`".

Example:

```
→ tree -a .
.
├── dir1
│   └── file3
├── file1
└── file2
→ tar --transform 's,^,directory/,' -zvcf backup.tar.gz *
dir1/
dir1/file3
file1
file2
→ tar tf backup.tar.gz
directory/dir1/
directory/dir1/file3
directory/file1
directory/file2
→ mkdir tmp && cd tmp/
→ tar xf ../backup.tar.gz
→ tree -a .
.
└── directory
    ├── dir1
    │   └── file3
    ├── file1
    └── file2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*` (at the end of your tar command) expands to "everything in the current directory", and all of that will be passed as arguments to your tar command. Try to run

```
echo *
```

to see what I mean.

You probably want something like:

```
cd /home/user
tar zcvf backup.tar.gz directory
```

Comment: Gnu tar 1.29 complains: `tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options`when you leave out a dash with the options.

Comment: @Roadowl Weird: my "tar (GNU tar) 1.29" does not complain.

Comment: Idiocy! My tar is aliased (prob. since ver long ago) to `tar --no-same-permissions --no-same-owner`, and apparently it chokes when these long options (that have no short option equivalents) are NOT preceded by one of the options -Acdtrux`, whether or not 'dashed'. I couldn't find any mention of this behaviour in the manpage.